# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'update' of 'userSlice.action' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm creating a redux project for change the name and email state but when I start the server, the app not show in the browser and when I open the console it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'update' of 'userSlice.action' as it is undefined." The error show in the file of createSlice.js for create a user store name with the initial state name and email and I add reducers action called update and remove.
I've searched for this problem but I can not find the answer why my app did not show in the browser.
[screen shoot og my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uvA6.png)

below here is my code

createSLice.js file

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    name: "nando",
    email: "nando@gmail.com",
  },
  reducers: {
    update: (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload.name;
      state.email = action.payload.email;
    },
    remove: (state) => {
      state = {}
    },
  }
});

export const { update, remove } = userSlice.action;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

store.js file

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import useReducer from "./createSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: useReducer,
  },
});
```

Comment: `userSlice.action` -> `userSlice.actions`

Answer (score 1):

in the last line of your code you forgot to add a 's'.

correct syntax:

```
export const { update, remove } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducers;
```